# At the instant of fuzzball creation, do all strings instantly pop to its face?

Tags: black-holes, string-theory, quantum-gravity

Disclaimer: I'm not a physicist, just an enthusiast.

I watched [Samir Mathur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samir_D._Mathur)'s master class regarding [fuzzballs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzball_(string_theory)) in World Science U, and something is unclear to me. Just before a star becomes a fuzzball, all of its mass is distributed over its volume in some way. However the instant the fuzzball comes into existence suddenly all the strings that made up the matter inside the star instantly pop to the event horizon?

Or is it that the "hole" is created in the center of the star and then the strings collapse *onto* the event horizon?

Comment: Anyone? Or perhaps tell me why my question is so bad...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Samir addresses this in his [essay](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.06407). The proposal is that there are virtual fuzzball excitations even in empty space and the presence of mass (confined to within a certain volume such that the exponential number of on-shell fuzzballs cancel the Boltzman supression) puts these excitations on shell. As per my understanding and private communications with Samir, when a shell crosses its 'horizon scale', spacetime would fuzz inwards from the shell. So if you are sitting at the center of the shell, you'd get fuzzed at the end of the process.

Comment: First, I'd like to thank you for taking the time to answer this after such a long time :) secondly, can you perhaps try to explain it in more intuitive terms? I know intuition rarely plays a role in quantum mechanics, but still.
Specifically, when you say "shell" do you mean a 3 dimensional shell as in the surface of a star, or a 4-dimensional spacetime shell? Could you perhaps explain a bit about what that shell is.

Comment: Sure. To make the thought experiment clean, we think of a shell in 3 dimensions (so like those liquor filled chocolates with the liquor removed). We take the mass to be M and so according to GR when it collapses to $2GM$ it will form a black hole. Now imagine you have mass $m \ll M$ so that your gravitational effects do not come into play and that you are at the center of the shell. The question I am addressing is that within the fuzzball proposal, when will 'you' fuzz vis-a-vis the shell crossing $2GM$.

Comment: As per Samir's essay, the virtual excitations will become real when the shell reaches $2GM$ and the 'fuzzing' will be radially inwards (so it WON'T be acausal in the sense that if a shell surrounding you crosses its 'horizon radius' millions of light years away, the fuzzing would still take a million years to reach you).